# Extra <li> in the Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, listitem

I am just getting started with Handlebars js the output shows an extra `<li>` don't know where it come from and i am amazed why this is not interpreted by browser following is my code;

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/ynkJE/2374/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="name">
    <li>{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Handlebarjs**

```
var nameCon = $('#name').html();
var compiled = Handlebars.compile(nameCon);
var render = compiled({name: 1010});
$('ul li').text(render);
```

**Output**

```
<li>1010</li>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry about that just before posting it here i have tried that... updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) puts the text you give it literally in the element, handling it as necessary so that HTML special characters (like `<` and `>`) aren't interpreted as HTML. You want the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method instead:

```
$('ul').html(render);
```

<s>Separately, the code in your fiddle does **not** match the code in your question.</s> *(It does now you've updated the question.)* In your fiddle, you have `$('ul li').text(render);` (note the `li` in the selector), which means you're setting the content of the `li` element, not the `ul` element. So that would be like writing this HTML literally: `<ul><li><li>1010</li></li></ul>` which is, of course, invalid (`li` cannot be a direct child of `li`).

[Updated Fiddle with corrected selector and using `html`](http://jsfiddle.net/ynkJE/2375/)